# Pipeline-like calculations with intermediate files: should I use a build system?

Tags: tools, build-system

I have seen multiple examples of systems that are organized essentially like a pipeline. Each stage produces some intermediate files which are then consumed by the next stage. Also, these take a long time and contain custom code, shell scripts and everything else imaginable (as opposed to everything neatly written in programming language X).

Question: how does one develop / organize such a thing?

It feels like we could be using a build system, but in our case it's the code of the stages that is changing, not the actual input. So it'd be nice if I could choose what to rerun. E.g. if the project is about mirroring a website and extracting its contents, I don't want to wget everything just because I changed the later processing code a bit... but re-downloading the entire thing is still something we might consider later. Build systems usually do not give such a level of manual control. (Also, they are rarely capable of keeping track of what outputs depend on what units of code specifically.)

The other end is having a shell script with a single parameter specifying the stage to run. It's completely manual, reliable, but not especially convenient.

I was wondering whether this is a class of problem that exists elsewhere, and if yes, how do people solve it?

Comment: You might want to look into [gradle](http://gradle.org/).  I'm not familiar enough with it to answer definitively, but I've seen a couple impressive demos for use cases similar to yours.